# Is there a command to change the head on an armor stand without changing the pose in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm using Minecraft Pocket Edition in 1.12.0 and I want to make a horror map. I need to replace a Steve head with a Wither Skeleton head using commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /replaceitem command for PE:

```
/replaceitem entity <target> <slotType> <slotId> <itemName>
```

I play Java, so I'm not 100% sure, but I think this should work:

```
/replaceitem entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,sort=nearest,limit=1] slot.armor.head 0 minecraft:skull
```

This should place a skeleton skull on the nearest armor_stand. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to make it a wither skeleton skull.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
/replaceitem entity @e[type=armorstand,name=myarmorstand] slot.armor.head skull 1
```